# Using a Substring in LINQ causes query to time out?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to convert over an Oracle SQL statement to EF/LINQ that uses a substring. When using the substring it causes my query execution to go from 11 seconds to timing out with over 5 min of run time.

In my situation I have a 4 character value and I need to only include in the results where the first and third character equal "E". Am I doing this incorrectly?

Here is the Oracle SQL that I'm converting.

```
and (substr(c.operates,1,1) = 'E' or substr(c.operates,3,1) = 'E')
```

Here is my Linq statement.

```
&& (c.OPERATES.Substring(0, 1) == "E" || c.OPERATES.Substring(2,1) == "E")
```

Even with just checking one character position this will make the query go from 11 seconds to over 5 min.

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL being generated? (As an aside, it sounds like you've got a single field which is effectively trying to store multiple pieces of data, and could be better represented as four fields. That's a different matter though...)

Comment: Yes, I looked at the SQL that was generated through LinqPad (which is what I'm using). I'll post it tomorrow when I'm back at work but it looked like it should work. Also, you are correct about the multiple pieces of data in one field. I wouldn't have designed it that way but that's out of my hands. Someone else designed it, I'm just left with coding against it. The DBA handed me the SQL query and I'm trying to convert it over to EF/Linq.

Comment: @Caverman I assume the same query using `substr` is *not* slow not using Entity Framework? Because if it is, it sounds like an indices problem (using a function prevents the DB engine from using the index, unless you have made an explicit index for that function), in which case, the problem would not be EF, or your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Entity Framework can't translate `SubString()` method to sql, so it has to fetch all the records filtered up till that line and filter in memory. The best thing you can do is just execute your sql query through EF, like this:

```
using(var context = new MyContext)
{
   var result = context.MyEntity.SqlQuery("SQL string here").ToList();
}
```

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx).

Comment: So you're thinking I have to use an inline SQL statement instead of a Linq query?

Comment: Yes, for this particular query it would be better. `SubString()` won't be done on the database but in memory

Comment: @Caverman Remember to vote up/Accept if an answer resolved your problem please :)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck nope, not at all. In EF 6 or less (question is tagged EF4), no filtering is done at the client level whatsoever. If `Substring()` was not supported it'd throw an exception (in fact, if you check [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738534%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it is indeed supported). The problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Btw, as far as I know, not even EF7 performs filtering on the client for now, however, it is a planned addition